# How to tell someone that you still remember him?

Tags: meaning

How to tell someone that you still remember him? which sentence is correct?

> - I will never forget you.
> - I will never forgot you.
> - I will never forgotten you.

Comment: **still remember** means "remember even *now*". You mean to say **will *always* remember**. *I still remember that trip we took ten years ago.*  *I will always remember that trip.*

Comment: Which do you think is correct? If you have no idea, do a bit of basic research, for example by reading this: https://www.ef.com/english-resources/english-grammar/simple-future-tense/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you want to figure out how to write a sentence, sometimes it's easier to simplify the sentence. For example, if you take out the word *never*, it's pretty clear what the answer should be:

> I will forget you.
>
> I will *never* forget you.

The auxiliary verb *will* takes the bare infinitive, even when negated.